# Loop timer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to execute a piece of JavaScript code say, each 2000 milliseconds.

```
setTimeout('moveItem()',2000)
```

The above will execute a function after 2000 milliseconds, but won't execute it again.

So inside my moveItem function I have:

```
function moveItem() {
    jQuery(".stripTransmitter ul li a").trigger('click');
    setInterval('moverItem()',2000);
}
```

This does not work because I want to execute the trigger click jQuery piece of code each interval of 2000 milliseconds, but right now it is being called all the time and the script needs to be interrupted. Besides that, I feel this is very bad quality coding... How would you guys solve this?

Comment: when must the script be interrupted?

Comment: Hi, I will never interrupt it.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Note that `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are very different functions:

- `setTimeout` will execute the code *once*, after the timeout.
- `setInterval` will execute the code *forever*, in intervals of the provided timeout.

Both functions return a *timer ID* which you can use to abort the timeout. All you have to do is store that value in a variable and use it as argument to `clearTimeout(tid)` or `clearInterval(tid)` respectively.

So, depending on what you want to do, you have two valid choices:

```
// set timeout
var tid = setTimeout(mycode, 2000);
function mycode() {
  // do some stuff...
  tid = setTimeout(mycode, 2000); // repeat myself
}
function abortTimer() { // to be called when you want to stop the timer
  clearTimeout(tid);
}
```

or

```
// set interval
var tid = setInterval(mycode, 2000);
function mycode() {
  // do some stuff...
  // no need to recall the function (it's an interval, it'll loop forever)
}
function abortTimer() { // to be called when you want to stop the timer
  clearInterval(tid);
}
```

Both are very common ways of achieving the same.

Comment: Go with the first one. Its better. Just have the timeout function create a new timeout call to itself.

Comment: You make me understand obviously between `setTimeout` and `setInterval `, Thank @Miguel Ventura

Comment: @a432511 They seem to be slightly different to me, but I'm not sure about implementation. In setInterval, does it start the timer at the beginning or end? If it starts the timer at the end, the real delay is the given delay + the time to execute the code. I reckon setInterval would be more accurate to the delay you provide.

Answer (score 8):

```
setInterval(moveItem, 2000);
```

is *the* way to execute the function `moveItem` every 2 seconds. The main problem in your code is that you're calling `setInterval` inside of, rather than outside of, the callback. If I understand what you're trying to do, you can use this:

```
function moveItem() {
    jQuery('.stripTransmitter ul li a').trigger('click');
}

setInterval(moveItem, 2000);
```

N.B.:Don't pass strings to `setTimeout` or `setInterval` - best practice is to pass an anonymous function or a function identifier (as I did above). Also, be careful to not mix single and double quotes. Pick one and stick with it.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
function moveItem() {
  jQuery(".stripTransmitter ul li a").trigger('click');
}
setInterval(moveItem,2000);
```

`setInterval(f, t)` calls the the argument function, `f`, once every `t` milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here the Automatic loop function with html code. I hope this may be useful for someone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
position: relative;
background-color: #abc;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p><button id="go">Run »</button></p>
<div class="block"></div>
<script>

function test() {
$(".block").animate({left: "+=50", opacity: 1}, 500 );
   setTimeout(mycode, 2000);
};
$( "#go" ).click(function(){
test();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sBxWH/)**

Answer (score -2):

You should try something like this:

```
 function update(){
    i++;
    document.getElementById('tekst').innerHTML = i;
    setInterval(update(),1000);
    }
```

This means that you have to create a function in which you do the stuff you need to do, and make sure it will call itself with an interval you like. In your body onload call the function for the first time like this:

```
<body onload="update()">
```

Comment: Code is broken. You're passing `undefined` to setInterval and recursively calling `update()` forever without any pause. (hint: the return value of update() is what you are passing to setInterval here)

Comment: -1 you create a new repeating interval every time you call this function .. its plain wrong .. and has the same problem the OP is asking help for ..