# redirect a page automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to automatically redirect an ASP.NET page to another after 1 minute using c# code.

Comment: Does it must need be coded in `C#`? Or can you use a html meta refresh tag...

Answer (score 20):

You can use something like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60; url=http://your.new/url/here" />
```

The "60" is the time in seconds to wait before page redirect.

Answer (score 10):

Try this one line code:
Here 5 means redirecting after 5 seconds, and make it 60 if you want to redirect after 1 minute.

```
protected void btnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "5;URL=YourNextPage.aspx");  
}
```

This code you can also put in `Load` event of the page so that it'll redirect to another page after loading current page.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use C# code to redirect after a certain time from the server side, since C# is executed on server side. You can do this by having the meta tag in your HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300; url=newlocation">
```

You can write code in C# to create this tag, Here is an example:

```
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();  
HtmlHead head = (HtmlHead)Page.Header;

meta.HttpEquiv= "refresh";
meta.Content = "300; url=newlocation";
head.Controls.Add(meta);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do so using:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Wait(60); 
Response.Redirect("Somepage.aspx");
```

Edit:

```
System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait(60);
Response.Redirect("Somepage.aspx");
```

Comment: Thanks Pooya the above code seems correct but not working. Have you tested it?

Comment: oops! I missed something, you should use System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait(60) instead of that line. Good luck.

Comment: This does not work in the context of the original poster's question.

Answer (score 2):

Note: The SpinWait parameter is a cycle count and not seconds as the above suggests.

Taken from MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait.aspx

> The SpinWait method is useful for implementing locks. Classes in the .NET Framework, such as Monitor and ReaderWriterLock, use this method internally. SpinWait essentially puts the processor into a very tight loop, with the loop count specified by the iterations parameter. The duration of the wait therefore depends on the speed of the processor.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this but I love to use this code because it works well when used in many different circumstances.

```
HtmlMeta oScript = new HtmlMeta();
oScript.Attributes.Add("http-equiv", "REFRESH");
oScript.Attributes.Add("content", "60; url='http://www.myurl.com/'");
Page.Header.Controls.Add(oScript);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this on the client would be better than doing it on the server.

You'll need to use javascript to setup a timer and then redirect.

See this on how to redirect:
[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery/506004#506004)

See this for timers:
[Loop timer in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133166/loop-timer-in-javascript)

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Comment: doesn't have to be javascript

Comment: Better is subjective.  There are pitfalls in doing things in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I love doing my stuff in JavaScript :-) I love JS. Here is my JS solution .

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
setTimeout('Redirect()',4000);
function Redirect()
{
  location.href = 'your-redirect-to-link';
}

// --></script>
```

The page will be redirected after 4 minutes. You have to insert that into the head obviously.