# Change DIV class 3 times in a row and loop it

Tags: jquery, class, loops, cycle

I'm trying to make my `DIV` background loop between 3 images. I have a `DIV` and 3 classes, each specifying unique backgrounds.

On page load, I need javascript to append `.class1` to the `DIV`, then half a second later, remove class1 and add `.class2`; again half a second later, remove class2 and add `.class3`; finally, remove class3 and go back to the first class and start again.

HTML:

```
<div id="rabbit"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.rabbit1 {background: url(http://i.imgur.com/fd3fo.jpg);}
.rabbit2 {background: url(http://i.imgur.com/SHknQ.jpg);}
.rabbit3 {background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Utel1.jpg);}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XDUSA/

I'm sorry, I'm new to this and I don't know where to start. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var i = 0; // Declare a global variable to hold the current iteration value.
function changeClass(){
    $("#rabbit").removeClass("rabbit" + i)
        i = (i==3)?1:i+1;    
    $("#rabbit").addClass("rabbit" + i);

}
setInterval(changeClass, 500);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XDUSA/1/

`i = (i==3)?1:i+1;` can be written as:

```
if(i == 3){ 
   // If the code reached this point the class assigned to the element in last iteration is rabbit3
   i=1; //Reset to 1
} else{ // More room to increment i
  i = i+1;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks. Do you mind explaining what `i = (i==3)?1:i+1;` does? I understand everything else but this part. I get what it's supposed to do, but I can't comprehend how you achieved it.

Answer (score 1):

what your looking for is the `addclass()` and `removeclass()` functions http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ and http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/  on a timer http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

a good read for doing this is [Loop timer in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133166/loop-timer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Cybernate has the best solution, but if you ever need to implement a toggle function, you can always use .toggle(): http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/XDUSA/4/

```
$('div').click().toggle(
    function() {$(this).attr('class','rabbit2')},
    function() {$(this).attr('class','rabbit3')},
    function() {$(this).attr('class','rabbit1')}
)
```