# Show a submit button during 1 minute every 10 minutes

Tags: php, timer

I would like create an event where users can post some content every 10 minutes.

So, the submit button must be allow during 1 minute for that. Moreover, users can check a countdown during the unallow period.

Is it possible with JavaScript/jQuery or PHP?

Comment: Clientside verification (JS/jQuery) can be tempered with. I'd use a serverside verification (PHP), but you can use JS/jQuery to toggle the button and show the countdown. Maybe you want to update from time to time via ajax.

Comment: This is not possible in PHP since it is a server side language. You should try javascript and since you mentioned Jquery, the Jquery Timers -> http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers might help

Comment: @Armand This is not true. Of course you can check the submission in a PHP script (if it is allowed again), deny the operation and show an error.

Comment: Refer this examples: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133166/loop-timer-in-javascript 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914951/show-and-hide-divs-at-a-specific-time-interval-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, when the page loads you can start with the submit button disabled by default in the html markup.

then use a coundown timer, here is a jquery one that I have used before
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Click on the callbacks tab in the link provided for code examples, inside your callback/trigger function you will add the following javascript or something similar.

`$('#submitButtonId').attr('disabled', 'false);`

Comment: forgot to mention that the callback function gets triggered automatically when the time runs out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your php post method set the next time in a session var:

```
<?php

   //intser post code
   $_SESSION['next_post'] = time() + (10 * 60);
```

Then in your template print this js:

```
<script>
var nextPostTime = <?=$_SESSION['next_post']?>;
setInterval(function(){
    if((new Date()).getTime() > nextPostTime ){
       $('#newpostID').show(); // this is the element id of the form 
       setTimeout(function(){
            $('#newpostID').hide();
            nextPostTime = (new Date()).setMinutes((new Date()).getMinutes + 1)
        }
       ,60000);

    }
}, 1000);
```