# iOS UI Automation wait until web view is ready and rendered

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am creating an iOS UI Automation javascript using Instruments to automate taking a screenshot for my iOS app. The tool I am using to automate taking a screenshot is [Snapshot](https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot).

I am using a webview for part of my app and I want to take a screenshot of fully rendered webview before proceeding to the rest of the script.
So currently my script looks like:

```js
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].webViews()[0].links()[0].tap();
// take screen shot here
target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().leftButton().tap();
```

But when it takes the screen shot, the webview was not fully rendered so it's taking an empty screen and go back to the main screen. 
Is there a way to wait until the webview is fully loaded, then take a screen shot and continue rest of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Illuminator framework (full disclosure, I wrote it) provides a function called `waitForChildExistence()` in its [Extensions.js](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator/blob/master/Extensions.js) that allows you to continuously evaluate a reference to an element until it actually appears.

You would do something like this to wait up to 10 seconds for the webview to load:

```
var webView = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].webViews()[0];
webView.tap();

webView.waitForChildExistence(10, true, "a specific link in the web view", function(wb) {
    // the argument wb will contain the reference to our var webView
    return wb.links()["the link you are waiting for"];
});

// take screen shot here
target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().leftButton().tap();
```

Comment: Did you change the name? I'm getting 404 when I click the link.

Comment: Apple deprecated the Javascript-based UIAutomation tool in favor of XCtest, so Illuminator was updated and based on that framework instead.  The last revision of Extensions.js should be in this commit: https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator/blob/f7b7218e42c94a3768d2828c9c1a40388725984a/gem/resources/js/Extensions.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed style, put some inert style property (I used clip), and you can check with intervals of 1 second (if you use css files better create a class with it and use the class on element).

The function below i user to get the style computed.

```
function getStyle (el, prop) {
    try {
        if (getComputedStyle !== undefined) {
            return getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
        }
        else {
            return el.currentStyle[prop];
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return el.currentStyle[prop];
    }
}
```

The timer you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133166/loop-timer-in-javascript)

**Be aware of that computed style may vary by browsers.**

Hope it helps...