# Rails: How can I use Ajax to get the Balance Live From the Database

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I need to make it so on my webpage the gets the value of the user's balance live. Right now I have the following code to get the value of the user's balance: `<%=current_user.balance%>`. The only problem is that it won't update live or close to live (every 5s or so). How can I make it so that the balance can update on the webpage live.

I have read that I should use AJAX, but I am not a pro and therefore do not know exactly how I should proceed.

Thank you. Let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Is something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133166/loop-timer-in-javascript) what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, but I then also need it to update the value of the item live.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment I made I think I know what you need. Give the balance an ID and whenever the time component is doing its thing add:

```
$('#balance_id').remove();
$('selector_of_parent').append('<%= j current_user.balance %>');
```

That should take care of it. The j is short for escape_javascript and is needed for using embedded ruby.

Edit* OR (just realized this might be better)

```
$('#balance_id').val('<%= j current_user.balance %>');
```