# Can i add a timer to this Javascript code

Tags: javascript

So I have this Javascript code, however i want to make it execute the code after 5 seconds, i was wondering whether this was possible:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".feed-item a");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    links[i].onclick = function() {
        location.href="/mypage.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop timer in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133166/loop-timer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function.

**setTimeout**

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay.

[*source*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

**Code**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll(".feed-item a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function() {
      location.href = "/mypage.html";
    }
  }
}, 5000); // delay is the number of milliseconds (5000 = 5sec)
```