# Timeline that gets updated every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeline

I want to make a timeline that updates every couple of seconds and doesn't need the page to be refreshed(it would get the info from a separate file that updates on a server), is there any JQuery that will make this is easy? could anyone show me an example on a webpage? Also the data gets updated on a fixed interval of 10s if that matters. And if possible I would like to stick to just CSS3 HTML5 and JQuery

Answer (score 1):

Very simple js, no need for jQuery for the "update every 10 seconds"

```
// set interval
var interval = setInterval(mycode, 10000);
function mycode() {
  // your ajax request or your function call to fetch data
}
function abortTimer() { // call to stop the timer
  clearInterval(interval );
}
```

for more info : [great post about a similar queston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133166/loop-timer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

1. First do `$.ajax` request.
2. call `refreshTimeline` to handle your response data and display on
   `success` or `error`.
3. wait 10 seconds and re-Ajax again.

See this example:

```
     function request() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "your.php",
        data: {}, //if there data to send
        // recommended to use json and parse on success
        //dataType:"json", 
        success: refreshTimeline, // try to refresh if success
        error: refreshTimeline, // try to refresh if error
       });
     }

    function refreshTimeline(data) {
      //handle data as you like
      $("#time_line").html(data);
      setTimeout(request, 10000); //wait 10 sec and request again
    }

    request(); // start ajax request
```