# How auto refresh every 10 seconds multple divs with same class and different id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have multiple divs with same class and different id and i want to change div contents auto every 10 seconds. need to post div id to my php page and update result to div...

```
<div class="sayac" id="1">data1</div>
<div class="sayac" id="2">data2</div>
<div class="sayac" id="3">data3</div>
<div class="sayac" id="4">data4</div>
```

Comment: you can set `ajax` in `set_interval()` on page load so after every 10 seconds it will call refresh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop timer in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133166/loop-timer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Here you just need to use `setInterval()` with `ajax` function to refresh your div, Please try

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var mayVar = setInterval(refreshDiv,10000);
  
});
function refreshDiv(){
//you can call here ajax to refresh every 10 seconds
    $('#1').html(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5));
    $('#2').html(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5));
    $('#3').html(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5));
    $('#4').html(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sayac" id="1">data1</div>
<div class="sayac" id="2">data2</div>
<div class="sayac" id="3">data3</div>
<div class="sayac" id="4">data4</div>
```

Comment: But i need to post id and need to get data from this id then i can update div with this new data...

Comment: Do you mean from div `id` you need to get data? if yes then fetch all `id`  from `class` attribute and send it to ajax

Comment: yes i mean i need to get data from div id, yes but i dont now how to do...i thin i need to learn javascript

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.sayac').each(function(index, el) {
        var thisID = $(this).attr('id');
          $.post( "path/to/file.php", { 
            id: thisID
          })
          .done(function(data, status) {
            $('#'+thisID).html(data); //$(this) will not work here
          })
          .fail(function(data, status) {
            console.log( "error" );
          });
    });
},10000);
```

But there is not much error handling. I would also suggest that your `php` to ouptuts in `json`. This way you can return an array and have your code react accordingly.

Comment: If you'd use arrow function, `this` could have worked there.

Comment: Interesting @M1K1O, thanks for pointing that out. I will look into it !